# SAS stored process server vs workspace server

Tags: sas

SAS has a stored process server that runs stored processes and a workspace server that runs SAS code. But a stored process is nothing but a combination of SAS code statements, so why can't the workspace server run SAS code?

I am trying to understand why SAS developers came up with the concept of a separate server just for stored processes.

Answer (score 3):

A stored process server reuses the SAS process between runs.  It is a stateless server meant to run small pre-written programs and return results.  The server maintains a pool of processes and allocates requests to that pool.  This minimizes the time to run a job as there is no startup/shut down of the process overhead.

A workspace server is a SAS process that is started for 1 user.  Every user connection gets a new SAS process on the server.  This server is meant to run more interactive processes where a user runs something, looks at output and then runs something else.  Code does not have to be prewritten and stored on the server. In that scenario, startup time is not a limiting factor.

Also, a workspace server can provide additional access to the server.  A programmer can use this server to access SAS data sets (via ADO in .NET or JDBC in Java) as well as files on the server.

So there are 2 use cases and these servers address them.

Answer (score 3):

From a developers perspective, the two biggest differences are:

1. **Identity.**  The stored process server runs under the system account (`&sysuserid`) configured in the SAS General Servers group, sassrv by default.  This will affect permissions (eg database access) at the OS level.  Workspace sessions are always run under the client account (logged in user) credentials.
2. **Sessions.**  The option to retain 'state' by leaving your session alive for a set time period (and accessing the same session again using a session id) is available on for the Stored Process server, **however** - avoid this pattern at all costs!  The reason being, that this session will tie up one of your multibridge ports and play havoc with the load balancing. It's also a poor design choice.

Both stored process and workspace servers can be [configured](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/biov/63145/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003070328.htm) to provide pooled sessions (generic sessions kept alive to be re-used, avoiding startup cost for frequent requests).

To further address your points - a Stored Process is a metadata object which points to (or can also contain) raw sas code.  A stored process can run on either type (stored process or workspace) of server.  The choice of which will depend on your functional needs above, plus performance considerations as per your pooling and load balancing configuration.

Comment: Allan - I only use a workspace server at my site, and I definitely use the `_webout` fileref on a daily basis to send results back.

Comment: @RobertPenridge - indeed you are correct.  The documentation of the differences is here:  https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=stpug&docsetTarget=p1lxbssuprk9vln17qbwtpiz1uwa.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en - I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that link.  Seems I may want to update my site to use pooled workspace servers...

Comment: indeed, the ability to create STPs (using sassrv) should always be restricted and any processes created should go through an appropriate release management / review process.